# Passing filters to a View

Tags: 7, views

I think this is an easy problem, but cannot solve it.
I need to pass arguments from my module to a View3; suppose that i want to pass a part of the node title and need to get all the nodes that start with that value. I cannot expose filters because i have a particular layout that am not able to desing using exposed filters, so i need to pass arguments programmatically. 
I thought to use Contextual filters but i have not found a way to specify the "Starts with" directive ... What can i do to pass argument?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose is better to use exposed filters. You can hide output of this filter in theming - it still be working. Just pass filters vlue in GET parameters to view's page.